# How to return observations which are %in% a vector?

Tags: r, vector, subset, data-manipulation

```
# My vector:
day <- c("day", "night")
```

| Observation | Column #1 | Column #2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Day | Evening |
| 2 | Evening | Morning |
| 3 | Night | Evening |
| 4 | Morning | Night |
| 5 | Morning | Morning |
| 6 | Night | Day |

**How can I return observations in which columns contain at least one value in my vector?**

| Observation | Column #1 | Column #2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Day | Morning |
| 3 | Night | Evening |
| 4 | Morning | Night |
| 6 | Night | Day |

### Data Frame

```
df = data.frame(
obs = c(1:6),
Column1 = c("Day","Evening","Night","Morning","Morning","Night"),
Column2 = c("Evening","Morning","Evening","Night","Morning","Day")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

We use `if_any` in `filter` to filter the rows having at least a match for the columns that have `"Column"` in column names

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   filter(if_any(starts_with("Column"),  ~ toupper(.x) %in% toupper(day)))
```

-output

```
  obs Column1 Column2
1   1     Day Evening
2   3   Night Evening
3   4 Morning   Night
4   6   Night     Day
```